# Git commit and push via batch file on Ubuntu

Tags: files, batch, github, upload

Our team have to always submit code on git after their work. And on every PC there are a lot of projects. All system running with Ubuntu OS. So I need some solution for overcome this manually commit on Git.

It is good if we can submit them on a single click only (upload in batch mode folders of a PC).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a bash script, example:

```
#!/bin/bash
### project 1 ###
cd /project1path/
git add all
git commit -m "Automatic save commit initiated at $(date)"
git push origin master --repo https://name:password@domain.name/name/repo.git

### project 2 ###
cd /project2path/
git add all
git commit -m "Automatic save commit initiated at $(date)"
git push origin master --repo https://name:password@domain.name/name/repo.git

...
```

Then you can chmod this bash script with `755` permissions like this:

```
chmod 755 autosave-script
```

After that change to UI and open nautilus and create a link on the desktop and youre done.

If the script wont start at a double click in nautilus open the file properties and change it according to the following screenshot:

[image]

You will have to do this step on each machine you want to use that script.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Should be this file .sh (filename.sh) or anything else ?  Where I have put this file and how can I execute this file without terminal ?

Comment: Since Linux/unix does not that wild extention pattern yada yada you can even make it without the `.sh` which may be misleading later if you ever maybe do this script in phyton, just make sure the shebang is the first line. The `.sh`extension is only added as an indicator for us stupid humans :D

Comment: Ok and I how can I execute this file without terminal? Like double click on file and it execute. Right now if I dbclick on it, it is opening in a text editor.

Comment: Ah ok let me cover that aswell in my answer just give me a minute.

Comment: Thank you, most of done but only problem still there. I have added the username and password in file but still asking me for username and password after run this file. Rest commands are working well but username and password not filling itself.
#!/bin/bash
### project 1 ###
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/project
git add -A
git commit -m "Automatic save commit initiated"
git push origin master
git username
git password

Comment: the line should look like `git push origin master --repo https://name:password@domain.name/name/repo.git`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39015/discussion-between-vikujangid-and-videonauth).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Videonauth for the answers, for my working of this manner:

Put in a terminal:

```
git config --global user.pass your-password
```

Where you need to change "your-password" for the password of your GitHub account.

Next put:

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

This create the hidden file:

.git-credentials

and add new values in:

.gitconfig

This is possible see setting your file manager to see hidden files. In Dolphin this is with "Alt + .". In Nautilus, Thunar, Caja is with "Ctrl + H":

[image: see the hidden files]

**Note:** If you want to see the content you can open with right clic and open with Gedit

Next make the script to commit and push via batch file. Open Gedit 
and paste:

```
#!/bin/bash
### project 1 ###
cd /all/the/path/where/is/you/git/repository
git add .
git commit -m "Automatic save commit initiated at $(date)"
git push origin master 

### project 2 ###
cd /all/the/path/where/is/your/other/git/repository
git add .
git commit -m "Automatic save commit initiated at $(date)"
git push origin master
```

remember you must change the path for all the path where your repositories are, see this example:

[image: to understand where is the path to the repositorie]

**Note:** You can do this with all repositories that you want. In this example is for two repositories, but you can do it for four or five, only copy and paste and change the values.

save in your HOME with this name:

autosave-script

then put in the terminal:

```
chmod 755 autosave-script
```

next if you want to see what all happen, put in terminal:

```
./autosave-script
```

See this picture to help understand:

[image: image to understand]

this show all happen:

[image: to see in terminal what happen]

but is not necessary, just double click to make it work:

[image: just doble clic]